# RadGrid client side binding

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I've got a question regarding the Telerik RadGrid control client side binding. I want to populate grid with the cities on the Client Side. I've got a object City, which has a property Country:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Country))]
public class City
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string CityCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string CityName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]}
    public virtual Country Country      {  get; set;            
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Country
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string CountryCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Iso2Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string CountryName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual char RDC { get; set; }

}
```

I retrieve this data as a JSON object to the client side using the JQuery Ajax and WCF.
and then I bind it to the grid:

```
rgCity.set_dataSource(dataItem);
rgCity.dataBind();
```

Here are the Columns definition for the grid:

```
<Columns>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="City Code" DataField="CityCode" MaxLength="3">     </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="City Name" DataField="CityName"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Country Code" DataField="CountryCode" MaxLength="2"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
</Columns>
```

The problem is I'm not getting the Country Code column populated with the data. I think the problem is in data binding, but I'm not sure if is it possible to bind a complex objects.
I think should be something like that:

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Country Code" DataField="**City.CountryCode**" MaxLength="2"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

I appreciate any help solving that issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do complex databinding like that.  Instead, I'd make a new property that returned the Country Code directly, then bind to that.  Example:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Country))]
public class City
{
    ...

    [DataMember]}
    public virtual CountryCode{ get Country.CountryCode; }
}
```

Declarative databinding for the grid then is what you had:

```
<Columns>
...
<telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Country Code" DataField="CountryCode" MaxLength="2"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Comment: No problem.  How did it work out?  If you found it help, please kindly mark it as the accepted answer.  If it was not helpful, let me know what else I can do.

Answer (score 1):

You can just overwrite the 
Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.dataBind function by replacing
this snippet from the original minified telerik script:

```
var J = r[v].get_uniqueName();
            var n = this.getCellByColumnUniqueName(H, J);
            if (!n) {
                continue;
            }var D = r[v]._data.DataField;
            if (typeof (D) == "undefined") {
                D = J;
            } var h = this._dataSource[u][D];
            if (h == null) {
                h = "";
```

with something, for example, like this:

```
var J = r[v].get_uniqueName();
            var n = this.getCellByColumnUniqueName(H, J);
            if (!n) {
                continue;
            }var D = r[v]._data.DataField;
            if (typeof (D) == "undefined") {
                D = J;
            }
            //change here to eval the dataField
             var h = AvoidEvalDueToPerformance(this._dataSource[u], D);
            if (h == null) {
                h = "";
```

AvoidEvalDueToPerformance function is defined as follows:

```
function AvoidEvalDueToPerformance(object, propertyString) {
    var k = propertyString.split(".");
        for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++)
            if (object[k[i]]) object = object[k[i]];
            else return object;
    return object;
}
```

Hope this helps someone as this was the first result i stumbled upon searching for the answer of question "How to bind RadGrid to complex object clientside"
P.S. to overwrite a function you could write

```
Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.dataBind.prototype = function(){
  //copy-paste the  Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.dataBind.prototype contents 
  //from your favorite javascript debugger output
  //(or grep output or w/e you prefer) here :)<br />
}
```